# In custom middleware, there are no route data values

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code in startup.cs (.net core 3.1)

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UsePreAuthorizationMiddleware(); //<---
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Extension method for custom middleware

```
    public static class CustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
       public static IApplicationBuilder UsePreAuthorizationMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
       {
           return builder.UseMiddleware<PreAuthorizationMiddleware>();
       }
    }
```

In the middleware the routedata has no values (length is 0)

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var rv = httpContext.GetRouteData();
```

I also have a custom authorization handler that fires right after this middleware, there it correctly has the expected route data. The expected Url/Page loads successfully, but I need the route data in the custom middleware. Anyone can tell me what I am missing? BTW, I also tried the httpcontextaccessor in the middleware with same result.

Here is the request that matched the routing.

```
    [Authorize(Policy = AppPolicies.CanEditRecord)]
    [HttpGet("{id:Guid}/[action]", Name = "Record_Open")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OpenRecordAsync(bool edit = false, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
```

Comment: Can you share your request which cannot get route data?

Comment: @YiyiYou Just edited the post to add the request details

Answer (score 0):

If your route is `{id:Guid}/[action]`,and you want to get the value of id in middleware,try to use:

```
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var data = Request.Path.ToString().Split("/");
        var id = data [data.Length - 2];
    }
```